# A farmer is growing tomatoes

Tags: probability

Say a tomato farmer receives four bags of 50 seeds each of 4 types of heirloom tomatoes, let’s say [Hillbillys](https://www.totallytomato.com/product/T00347/85), [Mortgage Lifters](https://www.southernexposure.com/products/mortgage-lifter-radiator-charlie-s-tomato/), [Purple Cherokees](https://hudsonvalleyseed.com/products/cherokee-purple-tomato), and [Brandywine reds](https://www.burpeehomegardens.com/Vegetables/PlantDetails.aspx?plantid=5153).

However the sender warns the farmer that the chances of successfully getting a tomato plant from seed is 50%.

Given that these are specialty tomatoes, the farmer is growing them for his/her own personal consumption and enjoyment, he/she would like to grow and try at least one tomato of each variety. For greater chances of success he/she plants 7 seeds in a row of each variety, because he/she doesn’t have room to plant 4 rows of 50 seeds.

*What are the chances that at least one tomato plant of each variety sprouts successfully from seed?*

I tried going row by row with S for success and F for failure, thus all elements of the form SSSFSFF, counting them and then dividing to get the probability for one row $\frac{2^7 -1}{2^7}$, but other than that I don’t know where to start for the whole system.

Also, in general, what if the probability of success was $0<c<1$ and failure $1-c$ and each variety had it’s own probability of success, $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: For each $i=1,2,3,4$ let $X_i=1$ if the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of seven seeds has at least one successful sprout and $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $X_i \sim \text{Bernoilli}\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^7}\Big)$ and $$X=X_1+ \dots + X_4 \sim \text{Binomial}\Bigg(4,1-\frac{1}{2^7}\Bigg)$$ You're looking to compute $P(X=4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end, it seems like you have $4$ rows of $7$ seeds each and each row of a different variety. The probability that a seed germinates is $p = \frac{1}{2}$ and that it does not germinate is $1 - p = \frac{1}{2}$.

If $X$ is the event of at least one seed germinating and considering that germination of each seed is an independent event

$P(X_1) = P(X_2) = P(X_3) = P(X_4) = 1 - \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^7$

where $(\frac{1}{2})^7$ is the probability that no seed in a given row germinates.

Now the probability that we have at least one seed of each variety germinate,

$P = \displaystyle \big(1 - \frac{1}{2^7}\big)^4$

Comment: What about in general? Where each tomato variety has a different propagation probability $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$?

Comment: Similar. In that case we have $P(X_1) = 1 - (1 - c_1)^7$. Similarly for others. Then we multiply $P(X_1) \times P(X_2) \times P(X_3) \times P(X_4)$ to find probability that at least one of the seeds will germinate for each variety.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why do we multiply the probabilities at the end?

Comment: Because they are all independent events. For independent events $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B)$. Take a simple example, if I toss a coin, the probability of $P(H) = \frac{1}{2}$. Now if we toss two coins simultaneously and we want to find probability of both turning head, the probability will be $ = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$